# Convert one column in a table to Hex and leave the rest of the data the same

Tags: mysql, sql, hex

I'm trying to convert one column in a file to hex using SQL. Example I have a table with 5 fields, 1,2,3,4,5. I want the 4th one only to be converted to hex. but if I enter the following:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, HEX(TKEN) as TKEN, field5, REST FROM table
```

They all convert to hex, but I just want the one. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast it first as BINARY.

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, HEX(cast(TKEN as BINARY)) as TKEN, field5, REST FROM table
```

Comment: It's actually a string, not a number.

Comment: That didn't work, the other values are still in Hex, and the TKEN field is now only 2 characters long instead of potentially 30.

Comment: Update, I use RDi, and the one of the front end features is running SQL commands, well that view shows all hex, however if I run the SQL from green screen I get the desired results, so I guess it has something to do with my view. My original statement worked.